# What is the process to get a winXP or win7 from its original harddrive into a virtualbox VM?

Tags: windows, hardware, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I've got a crying student in the hallway. It is submission date for an assignment paper, and his laptop died as it fell out of his backpack doing 30mph on the way in. The solid-state-disk seems ok, so were trying to recover the files by putting it into a mobile case and copy the files.

Right now, I need to figure out what the process is to get a virtual machine running (KVM or virtualbox) using the students solid-state-disks' winXP as his work is unfinished, and no-body here uses windows (we are all Ubuntu's).

Any hints on what to query (A), the process (B) or - if i'm really lucky - a script that does most of the works in one go (C) ?

Comment: Can't you just copy the files and edit them in Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, the chap uses some windows formatted files which I can't open. That's why we need the Vbox or KVM

Comment: Do you have the NTFS-3g tools available? You should be able to `mount.ntfs -o ro /dev/sdb2 /mnt`. Just guessing the sdb2, check `cat /proc/partitions` which partitions are available.

Comment: Hi Jippie, mounting is no problem. It is getting the windowsXP virtualised so the software he used to create the files can be used to access them. They're windows binaries. We can't open them, even though we can copy them to another disk (which we've done now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I used to do that all the time in class.

**Note:** Back up everything on the hard drive ***before*** you do this. You never know.

**1** - Install VirtualBox.

**2** - Connect and mount the Windows hard drive.

**3** - Find out which device represents the Windows hard drive by running `sudo fdisk -l`.

**4** - Run this command **as root** (replacing `sdx` with the appropriate identifer for the Windows disk).

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /root/windows.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdx
```

**5** - Open VirtualBox from the command line **as root**.

```
virtualbox
```

**6** - Add a new virtual machine to VirtualBox. Give it enough memory, set the appropriate OS, and for the hard disk, browse to the VMDK you created (found in /root/).

**7** - Download Super Grub2 Disk's [ISO](http://download.berlios.de/supergrub/super_grub2_disk_hybrid_1.99b1.iso). Add the ISO to the VM, as a virtual CD. This will allow you to boot to Windows without having to go to all sorts of trouble with a fake MBR.

**8** - Boot the VM. Once inside Super Grub2 Disk's menu, select "Find any operating system".

**9** - You should see the Windows installation in the list now. Select it using the arrow keys and press Enter.

**10** - Windows should now boot.

Comment: Thanks for the steps. I got no error messages in the process, but I do not see the XP desktop when powering it up in step 7. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the boot loader didn't follow correctly? Try downloading [this ISO](http://forja.cenatic.es/frs/download.php/1384/super_grub2_disk_hybrid_1.99b1.iso). It's Super Grub Disk 2, and it allows you to boot into systems with bad boot loaders and invalid MBRs. Add the ISO to the VM, so that it shows up as a CD. Boot, and select "Find any operating system". This should find Windows. Select it and press Enter. Windows should now load.

Comment: Great! I'll add the steps to my answer in case anyone needs it later. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can still boot Windows off that drive you could try Systernals Disk2VHD which will create a VHD for you. But dd and vboxmanage seem to be the better solution.